# Best use for handling multiple IF statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm wondering the best way to go about this: In my scenario users select between 1 - 5 options, depending on their options it has to randomly pick between the three.

Say the user has Option 2 and 3 Picked, I could write an IF statement saying when it's picked do this etc, the problem is I don't want to write IF statements for all the possible combinations.

Just wondering what's the easiest way about this?

I could go a Switch I guess, but again that would involve programming out up each individual combination.

Thanks.

Edit: Code for a small example

```
bool Option1 = false;
bool Option2 = false;
bool Option3 = false;

if (Option1 == true && Option2 == false && Option3 == false)
{
//Do Somthing
}
else if (Option1 == true && Option2 == true && Option3 == false)
{
//Do Somthing
}
else if (Option1 == true && Option2 == false && Option3 == true )
{
//Do Somthing
}
```

And so on..

Comment: Can you post an example of your code so we know what's going on?

Comment: @AshleyDavies added some

Comment: In this kind of situation I prefer to write code in more understandable language.

Option1 Option2 is never a choice of variable name for me or I will create few variables that names explain what they are intend to.

If you can provide more information about the variables you used. I can suggess you good code writing max.

Comment: You should take a look at following [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15905109)

Answer (score 5):

Try to write your code so it's closely tied to the logic you're trying to model. Does the choice made for `option1` change the meaning of the other options, or are they all to be taken as a group?

You might find it useful to introduce other flags (e.g. `exactlyTwoOptionsSelected`) that you can then use in the branching.

By the way, writing `if (option1 && option2)` or `if (!option1 || option2)` etc. is going to be easier to work with than `if (option1 == true && option2 == true)` and `if(option1 == false || option2 == true)`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what `"// Do Somthing"` actually does.

If there's some code duplication between the options then put it in a function and call that. Or separate the duplicated code into a standalone `if ( Option1 ) { ... }` block.

As you mentioned, you can turn the valid combinations into an enum (5 bits is 32 values) and put it in a switch statement.

Comment: I forgot about Enums.. been a while since I've programmed. Thanks Tom that'll do the trick'

Answer (score 4):

I would go for nested if's. you can always group them in functions if it becomes too unreadable:

```
if( option1 )
{
   if ( option2 )
   {
      if ( option3 )
      {
         doThing2();
      }
      else
      {
         doThing1(); // no more alternatives
      }
   }
   else
   {
      doThing1(); // need to do the same as above
   }
}
else
{
  ... more or less the same as above
}
```

I think that is the way it was meant to be. And with nice editors it becomes easily readable...

hth

MNario

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
        int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
        int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (first % second == 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1 is multiple of number 2.");
        }
        else if (second % first == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2 is multiple of number 1.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers are not multiples.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```