# Best way to check multiple boolean conditions in C# if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

I have 3 booleans on my code (C#) and an `int32` property that depends on what booleans are `true` and `false`.
Whats the best way to accomplish this in another way than if statements like:

```
if(a && b && !c)
   d = 1;
if(a && !b && !c)
   d = 2;
//etc.. ect...
```

EDIT: The 3 booleans must have every combination possible to set the int32 value.

EDIT 2: The value of "d" can be the same for two different boolean comparations.

Comment: If there are always exactly three booleans, you could build a table ahead of time and then just look up the specific item using the booleans as keys.

Comment: An array of integers and then the 3 booleans used as single bits to index the proper entry. Kind of compact representation of a binary tree.

Comment: To the EDIT: my answer shows how to calculate a 'combination index' from the constituent conditions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is better to capture the intent of the operation instead of explicitly check the boolean values.

For example:

```
public void Check()
{
   if (HasOrdered())
   {
      // do logic
   }
}

private bool HasOrdered()
{
    return a && !b && !c;
}

private bool HasBooked()
{
    return a && b && !c;
}
```

Comment: +1 Strongly agree, whichever is the most compact way to check that conditions we shouldn't forget the domain.

Comment: +1 here too. I still posted my answer because it isn't clear from the OP that his scenario lends itself for 'descriptive domain name'

Comment: If he wants to make terse code this kind of defeats the purpose

Answer (score 12):

You could use a Karnaugh map to reduce your equations and have fewer ifs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: This is the best solution I am shocked so many people didn't suggest this.

Comment: @Ramhound many people will simply prefer to write the logic _as it arises_, not how it _effectively combines_, eventually; K-maps focus on the outcome _only_ and ruthlessly eliminate any information from the input that doesn't influence the result anymore. This information is therefore no longer apparent from the source. Hene, the source is no longer a reflection of functional requirements. It's _harder_ to prove right, not _easier_. Even harder to maintain (modify). Instead, usually you should let the compiler worry about optimizing (which can happen even after inlining).

Comment: Some sample C# code would be nice... :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the lookup table hint given by @Adriano, assuming you have `lookup_table` filled with values for index [0..8):

```
var index = new [] { a,b,c }.Aggregate(0, (a,i) => return 2*a + (i?1:0));

int d = lookup_table[index];
```

---

**Edit** The EDIT of the question made this irrelevant: <strike>What does d mean?</strike>

If it's the count of false values (possible from the sample code), make it

```
int d = new [] { a,b,c }.Count(b => !b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what your doing now is perfectly fine and any other solutions would be down to preference.

My preference, where it applies would be to separate the checks out if possible.

```
 if (!a)
    return;
 if (!b)
    return;
 if (!c)
    return;
```

This would be useful in the event that you need to check certain prereqs before issuing a function, like if the user has logged in, if a parameter exists and is in the right context, along with other items.

*Like i said this might not apply but i just wanted to voice my opinion*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything *wrong* with how you're doing it, but if the output is the same for multiple conditions you *may* be able to simplify if by creating a truth table and simplifying the conditions.

For example, if `d` should be `0` *anytime* `a` is false you could simplify to:

```
if(a) 
   if(b && !c)
       d = 1;
   if(!b && !c)
       d = 2;
   ...
else
    d = 0;
```

Or if there is some mathematical pattern (e.g. `a`, `b`, and `c` represent the three digits of a binary number) then you could do bit arithmetic.

If, however, you have 8 *distinct* outcomes (one for each combination of `a`, `b`, and `c`) then your method is fine.